# ESP8266 more than one TCP Server

Tags: arduino, wifi, at-command, esp8266

I am using AT Commands for ESP8266. I want:

1. TCP Server at 80
2. TCP Server at 33666
3. UDP at 506

I am using this:

```
AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
AT+CIPSERVER=1,80


OK
AT+CIPSERVER=1,33666

no change

OK
AT+CIPSTART=4,"UDP","192.168.0.5",21,506,2

4,CONNECT

OK
```

Now If I check with clients, I can send and receive data on TCP port 80 and UDP port 506 successfully, but no TCP server is created for 33666.

Does ESP8266 only allow one TCP server for AT Commands? If yes, how to bypass it?

Comment: [Not with AT commands](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11451). Seems you will need custom firmware.

Comment: CIPMUX=1 need to set multiple connection limit to 4. It should work imho.

Comment: I have made mistake in posting code for my question. I have not included TCP server 80 code. Corrected. Question remains same. But thanks to @gre_gor. I got my Answer. "Multiple TCP server is not supported in AT Commands". May be possible in Arduino Firmware. Thanks.